# Will running MalDet (malware detection) and ClamAV (anti-virus) at the same time cause any issues with the operation of each other?

Tags: malware, clamav

I am running MalDet (malware detection) and ClamAV (anti-virus) on my RedHat 7.x server and wish to run these processes simultaneously.
Other than using CPU resources, can running these two processes at the same time have a negative effect (most importantly, can one effect the other negatively)?

I don't think they will but wanted to get any advice the community my have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be 'no'.

In fact, after linking both ClamAV and Maldet together, when you run a Maldet scan, it will also include the definitions of ClamAV and will actually improve performance for your MalDet scans.

Comment: It does not improve performance, you only see maldet scanner is fast because it ignored scanning all root files by default.